# Optimiziation in AMPL returns wrong result

Tags: mathematical-optimization, ampl

I'm new to AMPL "A Mathematical Programming Language". I'm trying to solve some equations but I found out that the answer is not logically correct (or as far as I understand!).
So my code is the following (after I found out the problem, I had to simplify it to understand it):

```
option solver minos;
var x;
var y;
var z;
maximize output: x+y+z;
subject to x_lim: 0<=x<=1;
subject to y_lim: 0<=y<=1;
subject to z_lim: 0<=z<=1;
subject to disable: if x = 1 then (y+z) = 0;
solve;
display output,x,y,z;
```

The output is the following:

```
output = 1
x = 1
y = 0
z = 0
```

but if I'm right, the maximum output must be 2 (when x = 0, y = 1, z = 1).

Now, if I switch the variables declaration order :

```
var y;
var x;
var z;
maximize output: x+y+z;
subject to x_lim: 0<=x<=1;
subject to y_lim: 0<=y<=1;
subject to z_lim: 0<=z<=1;
subject to disable: if x = 1 then (y+ z) = 0;
solve;
display output,x,y,z;
```

then the output becomes 3 (x=y=z=1) and the constraint (if x = 1 then (y+z) = 0) is not met!

The problem is somehow simple. I'm trying to group as much variables as I can to maximize the output and meet all the constraints as well.

Can you please help me understand it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is the cleaned-up version of your model:

```
var x binary;
var y >= 0, <= 1;
var z >= 0, <= 1;
maximize output: x + y + z;
disable: y + z <= 2*(1-x);
solve;
display output, x, y, z;
```

This prints:

```
output = 2
x = 0
y = 1
z = 1
```

I assumed that at least `x` is a binary variable, otherwise your model makes little sense to me.
Also notice the way I expressed variable bounds right at the declaration and not as separate constraints.

The problem with your original model is that AMPL is a *modeling* language and not a programming language: You have to express `if` - `then` differently as in programming languages. See [Integer Programming Tricks](http://www.aimms.com/aimms/download/manuals/aimms3om_integerprogrammingtricks.pdf), under *7.3 Either-or constraints*. I know it is counterintuitive and painful. The `if` - `then` you stumbled into serve a different purpose and are not meant to be used with variables.

If you are using CPLEX, you can express `if`-`then` constraints quite intuitively:

```
disable: x = 1  ==>  y + z = 0;
```

It should work; unfortunately, I don't have CPLEX installed so I cannot test it.

Comment: Thanks man. This was an excellent explanation. I have cplex and I tried it .. It worked :D

Comment: Great, I am glad it helped! If it solved your problem, please consider accepting my answer. [Accepting Answers: How does it work?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/157577)

Comment: @user3787524 Yes? What would be your question?

Comment: if i want to minimize number of groups .. how would the code be? in the previous example, i want the result to be 2 (this means 2 groups, the first contains x, and the second contains y and z)

Comment: @user3787524 Unfortunately, I don't understand but it seems to be a different question. Please write up your question, with code and explanation, and post it as a new question. Don't worry, I will see it.

Comment: Thanks!! I will follow some techniques of graph coloring. I think it might solve the problem.